# Proper use of Sequel's save()? How to create new or update existing records?

Tags: ruby, orm, sequel

The Sequel gem has a `save` method that "creates or updates the record". I'm trying to use it for creating a new record, when one doesn't exist, or updating fields for existing records:

```
record = Records.where(:name => 'Dark Side of the Moon').first
record.save(:artist => "Pink Floyd")
```

This fails, because `Records.where(:name => 'Dark Side of the Moon')` returns nil, not an empty Record object. Essentially, I'm using this method as an `upsert`, and it doesn't work this way, since the `save` method is a model instance method.

My question is twofold: (1) what's the correct way of using `save`, and (2) does Sequel have a way of "upserting" records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use Model#save if you have a model instance.  You can do that by creating a new model instance if there isn't one already in the database (when `nil` is returned).

```
record = Records[:name => 'Dark Side of the Moon'] || Records.new(:name => 'Dark Side of the Moon')
record.save(:artist => "Pink Floyd")
```

Comment: Also relevant is Sequel's [Model#find_or_create](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/ClassMethods.html#method-i-find_or_create) method.

Comment: `record.save(:artist => "Pink Floyd")` not work for me.


    record.artist = "Pink Floyd"
    record.save

works well for me.

It might be a bug in sequel (4.16.0)

Answer (score 1):

`record.save(:artist => "Pink Floyd")` did not work for me, but

```
record.artist = "Pink Floyd"
record.save
```

worked well. It might be a bug in Sequel `4.16.0`.